# html of CKeditor, edit of mathjax dialog

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am trying to edit the area of the CKeditor ( see icon). All this window is a Table with rows and columns, even the textarea is a part of a row. What i am trying to do is to create more Columns for my dropdowns and to move them higher, so i have first my dropdowns in a line and then my textarea. So is there a file responsible for these settings?
ps. I can't find the inspected html.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this can be achieved by using an Hbox (Horizontal Box probably).
add this code to mathjax.js

```
{ type: 'hbox',
widths: [ '25%', '25%', '50%' ],
children: [ 
           type:'select',
           id:'someid'
]
}
```

[image]